# Can I write a Mac App Store app with RealBasic?

Tags: macos

I am looking for an easy way to develop an application I wish to publish on the Mac App Store and I have tried Realbasic in the past so was wondering if this is a viable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, this Real Studio App was accepted already http://www.realsoftwareblog.com/2010/12/real-studio-and-mac-app-store.html

Answer (score 2):

My first answer would have been that you can't do that. Applications published in the Mac App Store are written in Objective-C with the Apple developers' tools and I have never heard of a RealBasic app published there (nor on the iPhone).

However, I found a page where someone claims he has done exactly what you want: http://www.tempel.org/RB/AppStoreGuide

Comment: I have found Flash-games on Mac App Store.

Comment: yes, I saw it as well, but I didn't think about them. You are correct.

Comment: That guide is by me, and it's now available for free from that link you provided.